# How to get innerHTML content of iframe element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

hi i am trying to get inner HTML of iframe element

my html document a structure is like this

```
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe id="frame1">
            <html>
                <button id="mybutton">click me</button>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

i am creating a chrome extension i have to show an alert when button with id mybutton is clicked i write an a content script

```
var greeting = "hola, ";

document.body.innerHTML='<div><iframe id="frame1" src="http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/"></iframe></div>' ;

var iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document

var button = iframeDocument.getElementById("mybutton") ;

if(button ==null)
alert("button is null") ;
```

i installed this extension in chrome when i visit a page then document body is changed into an iframe with a button in it.
but i am facing an alert which has button is null but there is button in iframe why i am  getting null for this button??

Comment: but iframeDocument is not null for sure

Comment: Maybe I mis-understand, but where is the domain of your parent page? Where is the domain of your iframe page?

Comment: If it is a cross domain iframe (I assume so as you have a fully qualified url in src) you cannot access the inner elements like other iframes. I use post messages to communicate between the parent & the child iframe if they are on different domains

Answer (score 8):

To get the button inside of the iframe, this could work:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var button = iframeDocument.getElementById("mybutton");
```

Obviously, you can navigate to get what you want with `iframeDocument`, and use `.innerHTML` as you seem to know. You cannot get the contents of the iframe if the iframe is pointing to a domain other than its parent.

**UPDATE:**

You need to use the code to get the frame's document and its contents **after** it's ready, so you should use something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var greeting = "hola, ";

    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    var frame1 = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame1.id = "frame1";
    frame1.onload = function () {
        alert("loaded");

        var iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
        var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        var button = iframeDocument.getElementById("mybutton");

        if (button == null) {
            alert("button is null");
        }
    };
    frame1.src = "http://onemoredemo.appspot.com";
    div1.appendChild(frame1);
    document.body.appendChild(div1);
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nqTnz/

The important thing is how the elements are created and appended to the DOM - not just using `innerHTML`. The `onload` method of the iframe is to guarantee it's ready. The actual manipulation code won't work in the jsFiddle because the cross-domain problems, but is what you should need.

Comment: var iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
var button = iframeDocument.getElementById("mybutton")
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
 alert('Hello World');
}, false);
i am getting error "Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null "
why i am getting this error iframeDocument is not null

Comment: Where in your code are you calling this code you posted in the comment? Please update your question with more of your code and where it's all being used

Comment: i am creating an chrome extension and calling it from content script

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta I updated my answer - you need to wait for the iframe to be ready/loaded. But you should reorganize how the elements are created/added, as I suggest in my update.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery's source code the solution to get the iframe document is like this:

```
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

And then you can usually use `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById` to select the DOM-Elements:

```
var elem;
if (iframeDocument) {
   elem = iframeDocument.getElementById('mybutton');
}
```

Comment: elem = iframeDocument.getElementById('mybutton'); in this line i am getting elem value as null but in console there is a button in iframe document for sure

Comment: have you added the first line?